# Implement SSH redirection on a remote host

Tags: ssh, openssh, port-forwarding

My problem is similar as the one described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine).
I've three hosts A, B and C.

A is the computer I get at home.

B is a server that we have at the University which is connected to the Internet.

C is a computer in the Office of the University. Connected in the same local network with the server.
So I can SSH from A -> B and from B -> C, but not from A -> C. I want a direct connection from A to C.

There is a great solution described [here](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html).

But my problem is that the solution is applied on A host and I preferred a solution that I can put up on host B because I want to make it easy for other users who desire the same connection.
I note here that most users are teachers who do not have computer skills.
Any help please.

Comment: If this is a solution for staff, it might make sense to talk to the network administrators to see whether server C could be made more easily accessible. Otherwise *you* might be liable for bypassing some intended (but unknown to you) security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here's better solution than the one given in the link provided in the question, since this new one has no dependencies on external tools like `netcat`:

```
Host C
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p B
```

in the `.ssh/config` of host A. Users don't need to have specific computer skills, they just need to be informed. Anyone can put 2 lines in a file.

If this is really a problem, a specific command could be added to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on host B:

```
command="ssh C" ssh-rsa <key_of_the_user_of_host_A>
```

So, when the user does `ssh B`, instead of starting an interactive shell on host B, the SSH server on host B will automatically run `ssh C` (see the sshd(8) man page). However this will prevent any direct logging on host B, and any other SSH command, such as `/bin/bash -l` in `ssh -t B /bin/bash -l`, will be ignored. As the man page says:

> The command originally supplied by the client is available in the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable.

So, there may be some room for improvement, either to run the supplied command on host C, or to run it on host B under some conditions (also be careful with quoting if you take this environment variable into account). One example is:

```
command="ssh ${TTY:+-t} C ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND-$SHELL}" ssh-rsa <key>
```

which runs the supplied command on host C if there is one (and will start an interactive shell as usual if there isn't). With this, `scp` may work, but on my machine it fails with "Permission denied" errors. But `rsync` works well and can be used as a replacement for `scp` if you have problems with it.

**Important.** Do not choose a solution that consists in opening a (necessarily non-privileged) port on host B. Either this will not work because connections to such ports are blocked by the firewall of the University, or this will introduce security issues as this will allow users to bypass authentication (with things like tracing) on host B via the SSH server on port 22.

Comment: Hi @vinc17, anything is working but I can use the `scp` command. When I run it, I always get this error `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` Please how can solve this?

Comment: @NGHONDATCHINDAErman If you want to use `scp`, you need to replace the command `ssh C` by a more complex one that takes the original command wit its arguments (from `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`) into account.

Comment: Thanks @vinc17, please do you have any sample that I use to that? or any link? I tried to googling but nothing found.

Comment: @NGHONDATCHINDAErman After some tests, the default seems to correspond more or less to `command="sh -c ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND-$SHELL}"`. So one needs to insert something like `ssh C` before, but the right solution seems tricky. I'll need to think more about it.

Comment: @NGHONDATCHINDAErman So, I've completed my solution. But I can't make `scp` work, probably because it is too complex (not assimilated to a simple command): I get "Permission denied" errors. But perhaps it works on some config, so that you may want to try.

Comment: @NGHONDATCHINDAErman Well, good news: one can use `rsync` instead of `scp`. I've edited my answer again to mention that.

Comment: Thanks so much @vinc17, scp is working very well. my `.ssh/authorized_keys` seems like this `command="ssh ${TTY:+-t} username@ip_address ${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND-$SHELL} " ssh-rsa <key>`, Where `username` and `ip_address` are the parameters of `C` host. I test the scp command and it works very well.

Comment: @NGHONDATCHINDAErman Great, I've updated my answer. I don't know why `scp` does not work on my machine. It might be due to some specific version. Or perhaps because I had to use a forwarding agent (with `scp -o "ForwardAgent yes"`), because all my keys are protected with a passphrase. Or perhaps because X11 forwarding is enabled...

Answer (score 1):

on host B:

```
B$ ssh localhost -L 2222:C:22 -g
```

While running everyone can connect to host C via B:2222 (tcp port 2222)

For a permanent solution you can run a `screen` on host B, and leave ssh command in the background.

(you can use a simplier tcp redirect software than ssh to localhost: e.g. redir )

Comment: For security reasons, the sysadmins probably block connections to non-privileged ports of B, such as 2222. Otherwise your solution may introduce security issues as authentication on B (via the SSH server on port 22) will no longer be done.

Comment: Thanks Sircer, I think the solution could work, but in addition of the security issues mentioned by @vinc17, we don't have the right to open the ports on the server.

Answer (score 0):

An interactive forwarding solution that doesn't require opening a port on B, but one on A, is the following:

On A:

`ssh -fNL 2222:C:22 B`

`ssh -p 2222 localhost`

It might be useful to know this in addition to the configuration proxy option (which works in a similar way) @vinc17 mentioned.